# Cannot figure out how to run a mysqli_multi_query and use the results from the last query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I've never used mysqli_multi_query before and it's boggling my brain, any examples I find on the net aren't helping me to figure out exactly what it is I want to do.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $agentsquery = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LeaderBoard (
        `agent_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        `job_number` int(5) NOT NULL,
        `job_value` decimal(3,1) NOT NULL,
        `points_value` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
    );";
    $agentsquery .= "INSERT INTO LeaderBoard (`agent_name`, `job_number`, `job_value`, `points_value`) SELECT agent_name, job_number, job_value, points_value FROM jobs WHERE YEAR(booked_date) = $current_year && WEEKOFYEAR(booked_date) = $weeknum;";
    $agentsquery .= "INSERT INTO LeaderBoard (`agent_name`) SELECT DISTINCT agent_name FROM apps WHERE YEAR(booked_date) = $current_year && WEEKOFYEAR(booked_date) = $weeknum;";
    $agentsquery .= "SELECT agent_name, SUM(job_value), SUM(points_value) FROM leaderboard GROUP BY agent_name ORDER BY SUM(points_value) DESC";

    $i = 0;
    $agentsresult = mysqli_multi_query($link, $agentsquery);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($agentsresult)){
        $number_of_apps = getAgentAppsWeek($row['agent_name'],$weeknum,$current_year);
        $i++;
?>

            <tr class="tr<?php echo ($i & 1) ?>">
                <td style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row['agent_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['SUM(job_value)'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['SUM(points_value)'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $number_of_apps; ?></td>
            </tr>

<?php

    }
?>
```

All I'm trying to do is run a multiple query and then use the final results from those 4 queries and put them into my tables.

the code above really doesn't work at all, I just get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\hydroboard\hydro_reporting_2010.php
>   on line 391

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay after some fiddling around, trial and error and taking reference from another post that I came across in a Google search I've managed to solve my problem!

Here's the new code:

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $agentsquery = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LeaderBoard (
        `agent_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        `job_number` int(5) NOT NULL,
        `job_value` decimal(3,1) NOT NULL,
        `points_value` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
    );";
    $agentsquery .= "INSERT INTO LeaderBoard (`agent_name`, `job_number`, `job_value`, `points_value`) SELECT agent_name, job_number, job_value, points_value FROM jobs WHERE YEAR(booked_date) = $current_year && WEEKOFYEAR(booked_date) = $weeknum;";
    $agentsquery .= "INSERT INTO LeaderBoard (`agent_name`) SELECT DISTINCT agent_name FROM apps WHERE YEAR(booked_date) = $current_year && WEEKOFYEAR(booked_date) = $weeknum;";
    $agentsquery .= "SELECT agent_name, SUM(job_value), SUM(points_value) FROM leaderboard GROUP BY agent_name ORDER BY SUM(points_value) DESC";

    mysqli_multi_query($link, $agentsquery) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($link) . "<hr>\nQuery: $agentsquery");
    mysqli_next_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);

    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $number_of_apps = getAgentAppsWeek($row['agent_name'],$weeknum,$current_year);
            $i++;
?>

            <tr class="tr<?php echo ($i & 1) ?>">
                <td style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row['agent_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['SUM(job_value)'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['SUM(points_value)'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $number_of_apps; ?></td>
            </tr>

<?php

        }
    }
?>
```

after sticking mysqli_next_result in there multiple times for each query it magically worked! yay!  I understand why it works, because i'm telling it to skip to the next result 3 times, so it skips to the result for query #4 which is the one i want to use.

Seems a bit clunky to me though, there should just be a command for something like mysqli_last_result($link) or something if you ask me...

Thanks for the help rik and f00, I got there eventually :)

Comment: I added a function `mysqli_last_result` to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

From the [manual](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query): `mysqli_multi_query()` returns a `bool` indicating success.

> To retrieve the resultset from the first query you can use mysqli_use_result() or mysqli_store_result(). All subsequent query results can be processed using mysqli_more_results() and mysqli_next_result().

Here is a function that returns the last result of a multi-query:

```
function mysqli_last_result($link) {
    while (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
        mysqli_use_result($link); 
        mysqli_next_result($link);
    }
    return mysqli_store_result($link);
}
```

Usage:

```
$link = mysqli_connect();

$query  = "SELECT 1;";
$query .= "SELECT 2;";
$query .= "SELECT 3";

mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
$result = mysqli_last_result($link);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];  // prints "3"

$result->free();
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Hi, I've read about these commands, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use them in my code. - I only want to use the result of the last query, the SELECT query... I don't want to use the results from the first 3 CREATE and INSERT queries as they're useless to me. - from what I'm reading those use_result, etc commands pull the results from each query, so how do i ignore all results and only use the final result from the select query??

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify what you're trying to do by creating a stored procedure which will produce the leader/agent stats and then just call it from your php (single call) as follows:

full script here : http://pastie.org/1451802

alternatively, you could probably combine your individual queries into a single select/group by statement.

see here : http://pastie.org/1451842

```
select
 leaders.agent_name, 
 sum(leaders.job_value) as sum_job_value, 
 sum(leaders.points_value) as sum_points_value 
from
(
select 
 agent_name, 
 job_number, 
 job_value, 
 points_value 
from 
 jobs 
where 
 year(booked_date) = 2011 and weekofyear(booked_date) = 2
union all
select distinct
 agent_name,
 0,0,0
from
 apps
where 
 year(booked_date) = 2011 and weekofyear(booked_date) = 2
) leaders
group by
 agent_name 
order by sum_points_value desc;
```

### Stored procedure

```
drop procedure if exists list_leaders;

delimiter #
create procedure list_leaders
(
in p_year smallint unsigned,
in p_week tinyint unsigned
)
begin

  create temporary table tmp_leaders(
    agent_name varchar(20) not null,
    job_number int unsigned not null default 0, -- note the default values
    job_value decimal(3,1) not null default 0,
    points_value decimal(8,2) not null default 0
  )engine=memory;

  insert into tmp_leaders (agent_name, job_number, job_value, points_value) 
    select agent_name, job_number, job_value, points_value from jobs 
    where year(booked_date) = p_year and weekofyear(booked_date) = p_week;

  insert into tmp_leaders (agent_name) -- requires default values otherwise you will get nulls
    select distinct agent_name from apps
    where year(booked_date) = p_year and weekofyear(booked_date) = p_week;

  select 
    agent_name, 
    sum(job_value) as sum_job_value, 
    sum(points_value) as sum_points_value 
   from
    tmp_leaders
   group by
    agent_name order by sum_points_value desc;

  drop temporary table if exists tmp_leaders;

end#

delimiter ;

call list_leaders(year(curdate()), weekofyear(curdate()));
```

### PHP script

```
<?php

ob_start(); 

try
{
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

    if ($db->connect_errno) 
        throw new exception(sprintf("Could not connect: %s", $db->connect_error));

    $sqlCmd = "call list_leaders(2011, 2)";
    $result = $db->query($sqlCmd);

    if(!$result) throw new exception(sprintf("Invalid query : %s", $sqlCmd));

    if($db->affected_rows <= 0){
        echo "no leaders found !";
    }
    else{
        $leaders = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach($leaders as $ldr){
            // do stuff
            echo $ldr["agent_name"], "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
catch(exception $ex)
{
    ob_clean(); 
    echo sprintf("zomg borked - %s", $ex->getMessage());
}

if(!$db->connect_errno) $db->close();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Kinda simpler now - hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help f00, but I don't think I'm quite ready for object oriented php script ;D that's completely mind boggling to me. - however I have fixed my problem! I'll post an answer :)

Comment: you can do it all in one query - see my alternative solution http://pastie.org/1451842

Answer (score 1):

Store result in a variable and in the end use that variable.

```
    do{
        if($result = $con->store_result()){
            $data=$result->fetch_all();
            $result->free();
        }
    } while($con->more_results()&&$con->next_result());
    echo(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to tidy up the poster's currently accepted solution to align it more with what I consider to be best practice.

- While multiple lines of mysqli_next_result($link) gives the intended result, it looks a bit hackish. So I'm going to create a DO-WHILE in their place.
- rik's solution involving the creation of function mysqli_last_result($link) is superfluous.  My WHILE condition will accomplish the same effect.  Additionally, rik's code mixes procedural and object oriented styles, which should be avoided.
- I won't bounce around between php and html.
- I'll just tweak the  class toggle a little.
- I'll put getAgentAppsWeek() directly inline, as I don't like to create variables that are only mentioned one time; and because Harry Weinert did a good job of naming the function.
- IMO this is just easier to read.

  ```
  if(mysqli_multi_query($link,$agentsquery)){
      do{
          if($result=mysqli_store_result($link)){ // ignore if no record set
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  echo "<tr class=\"tr",(++$i & 1),"\">";
                      echo "<td style=\"font-weight:bold;\">",$row['agent_name'],"</td>";
                      echo "<td>",$row['SUM(job_value)'],"</td>";
                      echo "<td>",$row['SUM(points_value)'],"</td>";
                      echo "<td>",getAgentAppsWeek($row['agent_name'],$weeknum,$current_year),"</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
              }
              mysqli_free_result($result);
          }
      } while(mysqli_more_results($link) && mysqli_next_result($link));
  }
  if($error_mess=mysqli_error($link)){
      echo "<tr class=\"error\"><td colspan=\"4\">Error: $error_mess</td></tr>";
  }
  //if any query returns false, mysqli_multi_query will stop
  // and the individual query error to blame will be provided.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I'll throw my hat in the ring on this question too (and hey it's still procedural and all that jazz). This is not fool proof, but I have fought and fought with MySQLi and it's band of merry men involved with multi_query and I couldn't get it to play nicely the way I wanted to, or have the flexibility that I needed. I saw several examples where some programmers were simply running `explode(';', $sql_statements)` which made my eyes bleed with how horribly wrong that can be.

My solution may not work for you, but this worked for me. (no it's not bulletproof either, but does the job for my particular application).

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents('test_multiple_queries.sql');
    $result = preg_split("/;(?=\s*(create|insert|update|alter|show|explain|truncate|drop|delete|replace|start|lock|commit|rollback|set|begin|declare|rename|load|begin|describe|help))/im", $file);
    $result = array_map('trim', $result);

    foreach($result as $sql_query) {

        // Procedural style
        $my_query = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query);

        // Now you can get errors easily, or affected_rows, or whatever
        //    using much simpler, readable code
        mysqli_error($link);
        mysqli_affected_rows($link);

        // or go crazy with some other stuff
        $words = preg_split("/\s+/", $sql_query);
        switch(strtolower($words[0])) {
            case 'insert':
                // do something nifty like...
                echo 'New ID: '.mysqli_insert_id($link)."\n";
                break;
            case 'drop':
                // obviously run this before the query, simply here for example
                echo 'Hey young (man|lady)! We don\'t drop anything!';
                break;
            case 'select':
                // hooray for selecting stuff
                while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($my_query)) {
                    // have fun with data
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```