# PHP and MYSQLI , function mysqli_multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use mysqli_multi_query function but it doesn't work. I think the echo will give me an error to print the $res value, but it print me "1". And so the fetch_array doesn't work because in the first parameter it doesn't accept number 1.

```
$sql =" start transaction;";
$sql .="insert into account (user_id, username, activation_date, passw) 
values ('$id','$username',CURDATE(),'$password');";
$sql .="insert into users (user_id,name,surname,birth,email,photo) values 
('$id','$name', '$surname','$birth','$mail','$foto');";
$sql .="commit work;";


$res=mysqli_multi_query($connessione, $sql);
echo( $res);
if($res != FALSE)   {   
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
echo mysqli_error($connessione);
   return $row;
} else {
print_r(mysqli_error_list($connessione));
echo "<br>";
    mysqli_close($connessione);
   return false;
}
```

---

P.S. In mysql WorkBench the values of the query are added to my tables. So i think the query works.

What could it be?

Comment: what do you mean by "*It doesn't work*"?

Comment: [This Q&A might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667596/cannot-figure-out-how-to-run-a-mysqli-multi-query-and-use-the-results-from-the-l)

Comment: What do you want fetch here because there is simply insert query.

Comment: @Martin - I *think* `$res` is a boolean in this case. The documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) says it returns a boolean. @MrCaptain Alex - why are you `mysqli_fetch_array`? There is nothing to fetch; you executed 2 insert statements.

Comment: @ Martin There is mysqli_multi_query return true or false so where is mysqli resource here.

Comment: @waterloomatt that would entirely fit the `1` / `0` result pattern. And I'd missed the useful comment above yours that the SQL is actually an insert so won't return a `resource` anyway!! `:-)`

Comment: @MrCaptain Alex - if `$res` is returning `true` (and it is because when you echo it PHP converts that to `1`) then I'd make a wager that your 2 inserts statements are working. But, I'm still not sure what you're expecting to see with `mysqli_fetch_array`. That function is used for when you're retrieving data, not inserting it. Also, SQL Injection attacks are not your friend. Lookup parameterized queries. If you can explain what you're trying to achieve maybe we can suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MrCaptainAlex you're trying to print the result-set (ie data taken FROM) of an SQL `INSERT` statement. This is illogical. As stated in comments by cleverer people; your query returns true (`1`) or false (`0`) as to if the query executed successfully. It does **NOT** return any *resource* or *data*.

Your SQL code / PHP code is the sort of code that would work with being given data, collected from the database -- a `SELECT... FROM` rather than an `INSERT .... INTO` .

You are treating your query `$res` as if it has just picked up lots of data from the Database. but it has only put data ***IN TO*** the database, not etracted any data ***OUT OF*** the database. Try running a `SELECT ...` query instead to pull data FROM the database.

Comment: I understand, i was making a big mistake. Thank you for patience.

Comment: @MrCaptainAlex no worries glad to help .

Answer (score -1):

you use "echo", but it should be `print_r($var)` for an array.

Can you use:

```
print_r($res);
```

To show us what you have.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, not that we're sure what that really is yet, Should be a comment